# Performance improvements for python-polars `df.select` operations

Tags: python-polars

I'm currently trying to migrate some code to `polars` but noticed some performance differences in the process.

```py
import os, platform, timeit, numpy as np, pandas as pd, polars as pl

data = np.random.rand(100000, 1)
df_pandas = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_polars = pl.DataFrame(data)

def timer(expr):
    return round(min(timeit.repeat(expr, repeat=5, number=5)), 8)

print("---- info ----")
print(f"platform={platform.platform()}; processor={platform.processor()}; CPUs={os.cpu_count()}")
print(f"python={platform.python_version()}; numpy={np.__version__}; pandas={pd.__version__}; polars={pl.__version__}")

print("---- pow(2) ----")
print("pandas:", timer(lambda: df_pandas.pow(2)))
print("polars:", timer(lambda: df_polars.select(pl.all().pow(2))))

print("---- sum ----")
print("pandas:", timer(lambda: df_pandas.sum()))
print("polars:", timer(lambda: df_polars.sum()))
```

The output of this snippet is

```py
---- info ----
platform=macOS-11.6.5-x86_64-i386-64bit; processor=i386; CPUs=4
python=3.8.13; numpy=1.22.4; pandas=1.4.2; polars=0.13.47
---- pow(2) ----
pandas: 0.00147684
polars: 0.01482804
---- sum ----
pandas: 0.00300668
polars: 0.00027682
```

These results imply that `polars` is much slower than `pandas` for operations that include a Python `select`, but are faster for ones that are performed directly on the dataframe.

In reality, my dataframe is much different bigger (`rows > 1,000,000`, `cols > 100,000`), where the performance difference is much more significant.

Any suggestions for what might be going on and if there is a faster way to achieve the same (or better) performance in `polars`?

Comment: What datatype is your real data? (integer or float?) Is it float32 or 64? Since it recently came up, floating-point summation can have different accuracy depending on implementation - that's also a factor one needs to take into account. And pandas varies how they do it depending on which additional modules are installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `polars >= 0.13.49` the power operation is optimized to a `square` optimization on certain powers. If I run this, both operations are faster than pandas.

```
---- info ----
platform=Linux-5.13.0-51-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.31; processor=x86_64; CPUs=12
python=3.9.12; numpy=1.22.4; pandas=1.4.2; polars=0.13.49
---- pow(2) ----
pandas: 0.00041451
polars: 0.0003346
---- sum ----
pandas: 0.00157432
polars: 0.00011628
```

Comment: I have `polars=0.14.2` and I did the same test (in a Kaggle notebook), and polars run much slower than pandas. Why could it be? 

`--- info ----
platform=Linux-5.10.133+-x86_64-with-debian-bullseye-sid; processor=x86_64; CPUs=4
python=3.7.12; numpy=1.21.6; pandas=1.3.5; polars=0.14.2
---- pow(2) ----
pandas: 0.00086124
polars: 3.85648806
---- sum ----
pandas: 0.00369703
polars: 0.27322495`

Comment: The dataframe construction from numpy has changed. Which I think is a bug. In any case, look at the shapes, you don't compare the same thing.

Comment: My run on `polars==0.14.4`:


`---- info ----
platform=Linux-5.15.0-46-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.31; processor=x86_64; CPUs=12
python=3.9.12; numpy=1.23.0; pandas=1.4.2; polars=0.14.4
---- pow(2) ----
pandas: 0.00044163
polars: 0.00042512
---- sum ----
pandas: 0.00169855
polars: 0.0001283`

So the issues are resolved.